# How to remove Backbone Marionette module?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tdd, marionette

I'm testing my Backbone Marionette modules. Before each test I want to setup a module on the application, and in the teardown process want to remove it completely.

I found only how to stop a module, but it is not enough, it doesnt remove event listeners, module object on application etc. And besides invoking the module definition again if more test cases exist, it doesnt create a new module, just applies it to the existing.

```
var application = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

beforeEach(function() {
    application.module('MyModule', function() {
        // module definition goes here
    })
});

afterEach(function() {
    // i want something like this
    application.remove(MyModule)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// assume you know the name of the module
delete application['MyModule'];

// otherwise
var module = application.module('awesomeModule', function(){});
delete application[module.moduleName];
```

Comment: and event listeners? it only deletes the object

Comment: call module.stop() before delete it. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#module-finalizers

Answer (score 0):

MyModuleYou could define it after and just start and stop when on before and after each methods.

```
var application = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

application.module('MyModule', function() {
    // module definition goes here
})

beforeEach(function() {
   application .module('MyModule').start();
});

afterEach(function() {
 application .module('MyModule').stop();
});
```

Comment: He doesn't want to just stop a module, but completely remove it.

Comment: this way tests might depend on each other if not all event handlers are removed

Comment: test should not depend on each other.i think you should add code to your finalize module events to do the clean up, your modules should be able to be started and stopped.

Comment: but how this is the question, reach the application and also remove it from it